# How to understand the tcp windows server connection issue?

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp

So, I am using telnet to connect to a host and port. But right after I connect the host closes the connection. So, I get the hand-shake of

```
[SYN]
[SYN,ACK]
[ACK]
```

Then, I get:

```
[FIN,ACK]
```

My question is what is the diagnosis of this type of connection problem?

I am not sure if it connection refused because of the initial hand-shake.
Connection refused? Firewall? Another type of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the server has closed the connection, which could be for a large number of reasons, including normal operation.